# JavaScript regex contains, but doen't match exactly

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of movie titles and a regex for the range of dates between 2010 and 2020. When I filter the list the regex doesnt match the string containing the searched pattern. How can I check if the string **contains** the regex, but doesn't match it exactly?

```js
const YEARS_BETWEEN_2010_AND_2020_REGEX = /^(20\d|201\d|2020)$/;
const MOVIE = ['Some Movie (2013)', 'Some Other Movie (2010)'];

MOVIE.filter((movie) => {
    YEARS_BETWEEN_2010_AND_2020.test(movie) // false for all
})
```

Comment: [Regex tutorial — A quick cheatsheet by examples](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried `(20\d|201\d|2020)` would also match 200 or 209.

A range from 2010 - 2020 can be matched using:

```
\b20(?:1[0-9]|20)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRY5Ps/1)

Instead of using anchors, you could use word boundaries `\b` as the anchors `^` and `$` assert the start and the end of the string.

You don't have to use `return` if you omit the curly braces in the code.

```js
const YEARS_BETWEEN_2010_AND_2020_REGEX = /\b20(?:1[0-9]|20)\b/;
const MOVIE = ['Some Movie (2013)', 'Some Other Movie (2010)'];
console.log(MOVIE.filter((movie) => YEARS_BETWEEN_2010_AND_2020_REGEX.test(movie)));
```

---

Another option to get a more specific match is to use a capturing group and on both sides match either any char except a digit or assert the start or end of the string

```
(?:^|\D)20(?:1[0-9]|20)(?:$|\D)
```

Or use a negative lookbehind (which is not yet widely supported by all browsers) asserting not a digit on the left

```
(?<!\d)(?:20(?:1[0-9]|20))(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the [start (`^`) and end (`$`) boundaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) from the regex. Including both of them means that the string from start to end, should have the pattern, not just include it.

```js
const YEARS_BETWEEN_2010_AND_2020_REGEX = /20(?:1\d|20)/;
const MOVIE = ['Some Movie (2013)', 'Some Other Movie (2010)'];

const result = MOVIE.filter((movie) =>
  YEARS_BETWEEN_2010_AND_2020_REGEX.test(movie) // false for all
);

console.log(result);
```